# is it possible to do an Ajax call in Server-side (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

As the question says, is it possible? I need my code in server side to call a third-party REST API to get some data.

Comment: Why cant you use `HttpClient` for making the REST API call?

Comment: AJAX literally stands for **Asynchronous JavaScript And Xml**.  I don't understand why'd you want to run javascript on the server...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @ramiramilu you can use HttpClient class to achieve the same.

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://mybaseaddress/");
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("someEndpoint");
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
 {
   var model = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<MyModel>();                
 }
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using .net 4.5 , You can do an [ASync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) request.

This is rather similar in concept to what you're asking for.